Is there a way to show that this large equation approximately simplifies to $d\sin\theta$ under certain conditions?
I'd like to know what the steps would be to show that
$$
\sqrt{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{L}{\cos{\theta}}\right)^2+dL\tan{\theta}}-\sqrt{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{L}{\cos{\theta}}\right)^2-dL\tan{\theta}}
$$
is approximately equal to
$$
d\sin{\theta}
$$
or if that's not possible without certain conditions, then under what conditions, e.g. $d << L$.
In case context helps, the question came up while studying the setup for Young's double slit experiment:

It seems standard in textbooks to assert, as above, that the angles of two rays (one from each slit) that meet some distance away can be considered equal, in order to arrive at a simple equation for the difference in length between the two rays. But I was curious what the exact formula was. So I sketched it out and found the length of the two rays depend not only on the distance between the slits $d$ but the distance between the slits and the screen, $L$:
$$
L_1,L_2=\sqrt{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{L}{\cos{\theta}}\right)^2\mp dL\tan{\theta}}
$$
I don't imagine this can be simplified any further, so next I wanted to verify that the difference between the two lengths approximately equals $d\sin\theta$, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.
Ignore unless needed
In case I made a mistake, here's the sketch I used. I'm saying ignore this unless necessary because I used different variables, which unfortunately confuses things. The $a$ in the sketch is really $d$ above, and the $d$ in the sketch is what I've called $L$ above. And the $\bar\theta$ in the sketch is the angle of an imaginary ray that begins at the center of the two rays.


Rationalizing your expression, by multiplying it by a fraction with both the numerator and denominator being the radical conjugate, gives
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
Y & = \sqrt{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{L}{\cos{\theta}}\right)^2+dL\tan{\theta}}-\sqrt{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{L}{\cos{\theta}}\right)^2-dL\tan{\theta}} \\
& = \frac{\left(\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{L}{\cos{\theta}}\right)^2+dL\tan{\theta}\right) - \left(\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{L}{\cos{\theta}}\right)^2-dL\tan{\theta}\right)}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{L}{\cos{\theta}}\right)^2+dL\tan{\theta}}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{L}{\cos{\theta}}\right)^2-dL\tan{\theta}}} \\
& = \frac{2dL\tan{\theta}}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{L}{\cos{\theta}}\right)^2+dL\tan{\theta}}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{L}{\cos{\theta}}\right)^2-dL\tan{\theta}}}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
With the condition $d\ll L$, then both expressions in the square roots are approximately the largest power of $L$, i.e.,
$$\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{L}{\cos{\theta}}\right)^2 
\pm dL\tan{\theta} \approx \left(\frac{L}{\cos{\theta}}\right)^2$$
Since $d\ll L$, then $dL\ll L^2$, so the third term of $dL\tan{\theta}$ is relatively small. Also, as you stated in your comment, since this term is added in the first square root and subtracted in the second one, they roughly cancel each other. This can be seen somewhat formally using Newton's generalized binomial theorem where, for $\lvert x\rvert\gt\lvert y\rvert$, the first $2$ expansion terms give $(x + y)^r \approx x^r + rx^{r-1}y$, so $(x + y)^r + (x - y)^r \approx 2x^r$. Thus, with $r = \frac{1}{2}$, $x$ being the first $2$ terms and $y$ being the third one, we see that last term roughly cancels out. This makes using just the second term of $\left(\frac{L}{\cos{\theta}}\right)^2$ even more accurate (also note the binomial expansion's next term is $-\frac{y^2}{4x^{3/2}} = -\left(\frac{\sqrt{y}}{4}\right)\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{3/2}$ so, with $y\ll x$, this will be $\ll 1$).
With this approximation, and $\frac{L}{\cos\theta}\gt 0$ (since $L \gt 0$ and $-90^{\circ}\lt\theta\lt 90^{\circ}\;\to\;\cos\theta \gt 0$), we then have
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
Y & \approx \frac{2dL\tan{\theta}}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{L}{\cos{\theta}}\right)^2}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{L}{\cos{\theta}}\right)^2}} \\
& = \frac{\frac{2dL\sin{\theta}}{\cos\theta}}{\frac{2L}{\cos{\theta}}} \\
& = d\sin\theta
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Ah, I did not know about rationalizing a denominator by multiplying by a conjugate (a link I found to help me understand). Thank you for that. After that, I understand $(d/2)^2$ being negligible compared to $(L/\cos\theta)^2$, but I don't understand how to reason about the combination of a small $d$ and large $L$ in the $dL\tan\theta$ term. Could you give more insight on why that term can be comfortably eliminated?

Oh, I can kinda "see" how the $dL\tan\theta$ adds a "bit" in the left square root and subtracts a "bit" in the right square root, i.e. they move in opposite directions. Perhaps that's the basis for their elimination? Is there a formal way to express that?

@AndrewCheong You're welcome. Regarding the elimination of the $dL\tan\theta$ term, I updated my answer with some more explanation. In addition to it being relatively small compared to the middle term, having it be added in one square root and subtracted in another does mean they roughly cancel each other, as you indicated. Regarding a more formal way to express it, I added about showing this occurring with the first $2$ terms of Newton's generalized binomial theorem.

Wow, Newton's generalized binomial theorem is powerful. This fully answers my question, thanks again!

You could even go futher for a bit larger values of $\frac dL$.
Continue with Taylor series and assuming $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac \pi 2$, you should get for the expression
$$d\sin(\theta)\Big(1-\frac{d^2 \cos ^4(\theta )}{8 L^2}+O\left(d^4\right)  \Big)$$
